# After importing MySQL db I can no longer log in to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Not paying attention, I exported a database from a MySQL 5.5 server, and imported it into a MySQL 5.1 server.  Both via phpMyAdmin.

No errors were reported in any logs.  I was also immediately able to browse the database as well.

No other changes have been made to the servers or the software.  However, following that event, I am unable to log into MySQL via phpMyAdmin using any available login.

I am able to log in via console, and have dropped the added database with no effect.  I have also updated the max_allowed_packet size to 16M per other recommended steps also to no avail.

When I try logging in, I get the following message: "#2006 Cannot log in to the MySQL server".

I have not been able to locate any additional information regarding fixes for this.  Any recommendations?

Options currently under consideration:

1. Upgrade phpMyAdmin
2. Upgrade MySQL (needed as well as required for item 1)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html  2006  = "server has gone away". things to try here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I did flush privileges with no effect.

Comment: @MarcB, I did look through that list, and none seem to apply.  At least nothing that would give reason to being to login, and with only the changes specified above, being unable to log in again.

Comment: then check the mysql logs to see what's happening.

Comment: @BK435, same problem.  It seems likely to me that there is something that phpMyAdmin does on login that is broken and causing the problem.  I can log in to MySQL from the server phpMyAdmin is hosted on, but not from phpMyAdmin itself.

Comment: @MarcB, I have checked the logs, and nothing is being reported that I have been able to locate.

Comment: @BK435, It was in use when I got here.  Now just trying to figure out how exactly it broke and how to fix it.

Comment: You are mentionning two MySQL servers. Are you sure that your phpMyA dmin is trying to log in to the MySQL 5.1 server and that this one is running?

Comment: There is only one MySQL server.  There are, however, two total servers: web server, and MySQL server.  In any case, I have verified that the server it is trying to connect to is the correct one.  At least the correct IP is in the config.

Comment: The second MySQL server I mentioned is inconsequential and not accessible from the web server.  It is only important as to where the original data came from that I believe corrupted something within the MySQL server causing the connection to drop when coming from phpMyAdmin on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to determine the exact cause of this issue, but a fresh install of the same version of phpMyAdmin (installed to a new folder) fixed the issue.

Thanks for the willing assistance.

Next up: upgrading the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your max_allowed_packet size to a bigger value, such as 100M?

Comment: I did.  No change.  And before anyone asks, I did restart the service following.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem in your phpmyadmin conf-file, double check the settings for db name, user name and password.

Comment: I have, and none of them are set which is the way it should be set up to require a login and access to multiple databases.  The host is correct as well.